# how to get the final result of html page by pyqt?

Tags: javascript, python, html

Recently I am trying to crawl data from Google search result and it seems pyqt is a good module to execute the javascript in html and get the final html result. However for other website, it seems work right. However, for Google search, it always failed. I follow an example here:
http://webscraping.com/blog/Scraping-JavaScript-webpages-with-webkit/

The code is:

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

class Render(QWebPage):

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()
        self.app.quit()

url1 = 'http://www.google.com/search?start=0&client=firefox-a&q=adidas&safe=off&pws=0&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2002%2Ccd_max%3A1%2F1%2F2001&filter=0&num=10&access=a&oe=UTF-8&ie=UTF-8'   
url2 = 'http://www.google.com/search?start=0&client=firefox-a&q=adidas&safe=off&pws=0&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2009%2Ccd_max%3A7%2F1%2F2009&filter=0&num=10&access=a&oe=UTF-8&ie=UTF-8'
r = Render(url1)
html = r.frame.toHtml()
print type(html)

outfile = open('page.html','w')
outfile.write(html.toUtf8())
outfile.close()
print 'finished!'
```

However, the result of url1 and url2 always get the same result, and the result is just the same when I disable the javascript in chrome. So how should we deal with it? How can we fetch the final html of Google search?

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys  
from PyQt4.QtGui import *  
from PyQt4.QtCore import *  
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *  

class Render(QWebPage):  
  def __init__(self, url):  
    self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
    QWebPage.__init__(self)  
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)  
    self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))  
    self.app.exec_()  

  def _loadFinished(self, result):  
    self.frame = self.mainFrame()  
    self.app.quit()  

url = 'http://webscraping.com'  
r = Render(url)  
html = r.frame.toHtml()
```

Source: http://webscraping.com/blog/Scraping-JavaScript-webpages-with-webkit/

Comment: did you...did you just post the exact same code as the OP had for your solution?